# Cannot create topic on AWS MSK cluster with SASL/SCRAM and auto.create.topics.enable=true

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

### Summary:

I created an AWS MSK cluster with SASL/SCRAM enabled and `auto.create.topics.enable=true` in the configuration.

I expected that my clients would be able to create topics but it doesn't seem to work so far. I get `Authorization failed` type of errors.

### What I tried:

I tried connecting to the cluster using two ways:

1. Using python (the package `kafka-python==2.0.2`):

   ```py
   p = KafkaProducer(
           bootstrap_servers=['b-2-public.xxx.c2.kafka.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:9196'],
           security_protocol="SASL_SSL",
           sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-512",
           sasl_plain_username="t9tXXX",
           sasl_plain_password="2p%wXXX",
   )

   p.send(topic="my-requests", value=b"test")
   ```

   and I would get the error:

   ```py
   kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
   ```

   > Note: to make sure connection to the cluster is working, I can successfully create a `KafkaConsumer()` and then call the `topics()` method to get an empty set (no topics created so far, ofc).
2. Using bash/java (`kafka-topics.sh` version `2.8.1`):
   I put the following properties in `/tmp/config.properties`:

   ```
   security.protocol=SASL_SSL
   sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
   ```

   as well as the following JAAS configuration in `/tmp/sasl.jaas.config`:

   ```
   KafkaClient {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="redacted" password="redacted";
   ```

   then finally run the command:

   ```bash
   kafka-topics.sh --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server b-2-public.xxx.c2.kafka.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:9196 --topic semi-structured-form-requests --partitions 5 --command-config /tmp/config.properties
   ```

   and end up with the error:

   ```java
   Error while executing topic command : Authorization failed.
   [2023-07-27 07:14:21,284\] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Authorization failed.
   (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
   ```

The MSK cluster configuration is the following:

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
```

Is there anything that could help me further diagnose the issue? Thank you.

Comment: You can use AdminClient in Python to create topics. Ideally, you dont enable auto creation on the broker side ... Otherwise, try asking MSK Support why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I know it's half year later but still might be helpful.

I faced a similar problem while trying to create a topic with `kafka-topics.sh`

In addition to the step described above, I've run the following and it worked for me.

```bash
export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/tmp/sasl.jaas.config
```

Documentation source is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html